# App crashed when invoking NSAttributedString.boundingRectWithSize

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I want a UILabel where part of the text is underlined to resemble a link. This is how I construct the NSAttributedString:

```
let attributedStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Some description.")
let underlineText = NSAttributedString(string: "Click Here", attributes: [
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.blue,
                NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single,
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)])
attributedStr.append(underlineText)

let size = attributedStr.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width:CGFloat(width), height:CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil).size
```

The app crashes on invoking `boundingRectWith` method:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[__SwiftValue _getValue:forType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28050bed0'
```

Why? How should I measure the size of the text correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value for the key - `NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle` should contain the rawValue at the end, like so - `NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue`.

You can see the code below:

```
let attributedStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Some description.")

let underlineText = NSAttributedString(string: "Click Here", attributes: [
                    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.blue,
                    NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
                    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)])

attributedStr.append(underlineText)
```

Comment: That's the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help, enjoy!